# Is it necessary to follow the stylecop rule?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, sonarqube, stylecop

My project now has to be put to SONAR which is the code analysis tool - http://www.sonarsource.org/ . does the styling from stylecop also matters in the code quality?
is that necessary to follow the stylecop? The steps in this site seems to be very confusing,can someone provide me the steps as to how to put .net C# code to SONAR?

i am using .net VS 2010 c# win forms

thanks in advance

Comment: What is your question? Is it about StyleCop rules? Or is it about code quality? Or is it about using C# with SONAR? Make up your mind.

Comment: @GrantThomas - my question was does SONAR is affected by styling also?because i have a very huge project with many warnings, no rules is followed from the 1st.

Comment: @roopinin Whether it is necessary to follow the rules or not depends on what the community rules are for code formatting of pushed code. Having a quick look at there site doesn't show any rules. My advice is to maintain style consistency with existing code and push it, someone will then review it before committing your changes to the main branch.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth- thanks, i have no idea on the code check as how SONAR does, does it also count the styling also, as i am new to this.May be this link http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/C%23+Ecosystem